# Alterar Font Awesome com toggle() - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um projeto e, estou fazendo um menu responsivo. Porém, estou com um problema de estética. Eu queria que quando eu clicasse no `fa fa-bars` queria que fizesse uma animação é alterasse o Font Awesome para o `fa-solid fa-x`, porém não sei como fazer isso. Vi alguns sites que diziam que dava para fazer isso com o `classList.toggle()`, porém não cheguei a nenhum resultado, já que quando eu vou colocar o ícone `fa-solid fa-x` aparece um erro. Aqui está uma parte do código:

```
<i onclick="menu(this)" class="fa fa-bars"><i>
```

```
function menu(x) {
   x.classList.toggle("fa-solid fa-x")
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <i id="eye" class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f2861a396.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var elemento = document.getElementById("eye");
var open = true;
elemento.onclick = function() {
    if(open) {
        elemento.classList.add('fa-eye');
        elemento.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
    } else {
        elemento.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
        elemento.classList.remove('fa-eye');
    }
    open = !open;
}
```